# Task not serializable in Spark caused by UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have some problems running my Spark Application on Yarn. I have very extensive Integration Tests that are running without any problems but when I run the application on YARN it will throw the following error:

```
17/01/06 11:22:23 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.map(DataFrame.scala:1410)
    at com.orgx.yy.dd.check.DQCheck$class.runDQCheck(DQCheck.scala:24)
    at com.orgx.yy.dd.check.DQBatchCheck.runDQCheck(DQBatchCheck.scala:13)
    at com.orgx.yy.dd.check.DQBatchCheck.doCheck(DQBatchCheck.scala:23)
    at com.orgx.yy.dd.DQChecker$.main(DQChecker.scala:60)
    at com.orgx.yy.dd.DQChecker.main(DQChecker.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 72887 bytes
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:364)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValueData(SerializedConfigValue.java:295)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValue(SerializedConfigValue.java:369)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValueData(SerializedConfigValue.java:309)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValue(SerializedConfigValue.java:369)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValueData(SerializedConfigValue.java:309)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValue(SerializedConfigValue.java:369)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValueData(SerializedConfigValue.java:309)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeValue(SerializedConfigValue.java:369)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SerializedConfigValue.writeExternal(SerializedConfigValue.java:435)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.writeObject(List.scala:379)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 20 more
17/01/06 11:22:24 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable)
```

The culprit seems to be java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 72887 bytes at. Anyone have any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the source code where the exception is thrown: `DataOutputStream.java:364`

Comment: @maasg I'm not sure that will be very useful as that is some low level Java IO class and frequently used by many libraries. I suspect there is something going wrong with the serialization of the Task and that it is hitting some kind of size limit.

Comment: If I were going to try to answer such question, that's where I would start, just to get an idea of what's going wrong. I agree that the issue is probably somewhere else, but you need to follow the bread crumbs to the bug lair.

Comment: From the Java API docs: Writes a string to the underlying output stream using modified UTF-8 encoding in a machine-independent manner. 

So I guess it is trying to write a string that is around 73KB and it is larger than some size limit. Apparently Java’s DataOutputStream has a 64KB limit.

Comment: That's what the code would say :-) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#363  So, there's a too long string in some closure being serialized. Could you post the code that generates this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue. The problem was that I introduced Typesafe config to one of the classes that were being used by the function that failed to be serialized. By adding the config this increased the total memory footprint and exceeded the 64KB limit.

When I removed the config object from the class it was working fine again.