# Broadcasting TypeSafe Config throws exception User class threw exception: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 70601 bytes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Just as the question title says I am trying to broadcast a TypeSafe config to the executors so my code there can access the config. Unfortunately, I'm getting an exception

```
object AppConfigUtility {

  var config: Config = ConfigFactory.empty()

  var brConfig: Broadcast[Config] = _

  /**
    * Broadcast the config so it can be available for executors to use
    * @param sc
    */
  def broadCastConfig(sc: SparkContext): Unit = {

    brConfig = sc.broadcast(config)

  }

  def loadConfig(): Unit = {
    //some actual implementation of loading my application.conf file
  }
}
```

When I call broadCastConfig in my main method it throws the below exception

User class threw an exception: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 70601 bytes

The final size of my application.conf is only 3KB or 3000 Bytes which is not anywhere near the 64KB limit so I'm not why I'm hitting this error.

Comment: application.conf is too big? can you give sample of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like you have ***long strings*** in `application.conf` which is causing the issue..

with [this :64KB String limit in Java data streams](https://www.drillio.com/en/2009/java-encoded-string-too-long-64kb-limit/) example you could prove that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // generate string longer than 64KB
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        sb.append("1234567890");
    String s = sb.toString();

    // write the string into the stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeUTF(s);
    dos.close();
}
```

similar but not same issue faced was fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41508519/647053)

I'd suggest parse the application.conf and set it to an object and send it to all executors using broadcast.

Means.. you can send any serializable object to broadcast... but  is in the form of application.conf

Comment: I actually just checked though, the final size of my application.conf is only 3KB or 3000 Bytes which is not anywhere near the 64KB limit

Comment: There is symptom which we are talking about.... Pls try the other way of broadcasting parsed object rather than conf directly

Comment: Accepted however the first part of your answer is misleading. Please see my comment where I mention that my entire config is < 3KB and this is less than the 64KB limit. However parsing the config to an object + broadcasting does work. I didn't parse the entire config because what I needed it for didn't need the whole config but it still gets around this issue.

Comment: alex : will try to replicate/prove the same if you post application.conf complete listing